# How can i Open .vcf file in my view controller in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, vcf-vcard

I have .Vcf File(Url) which is coming from web service.  and i want to open it in my view controller.

Anyone can help me for this.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/heardrwt/RHAddressBook to read vcf file

Comment: You can use `CNContactVCardSerialization` and its class method `+ontactsWithData:error:`

Comment: Thanks @Larme its woring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Solution

```
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.totalData valueForKey:@"file"]]]];
      NSArray *contactList = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[CNContactVCardSerialization contactsWithData:data error:nil]];
      CNContact *contact;
           contact=[contactList objectAtIndex:0];
      NSLog(@"%@",contact.givenName);
      NSLog(@"%@",contact.familyName);
```